# UNITY: Random error Assertion failed: TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error

[image]
Getting this error flooding the console with no reference to where it is coming from. Really not sure what I did to create this error it seems to just have appeared, I think it may have been linked to my update to 2017.3.0f3 but not completely certain.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is referenced here : https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/assertion-failed-tls-allocator-alloc-temp-thread-dot-dot-dot-error-is-shown-after-building-the-project-for-ios

I have the same errors on my project, waiting for a fix :)